# Grouped Select2 Drop Down (Select) refresh issue

Tags: jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

We have built a site that contains search functionality allowing the user to drill down a list of results via a series of drop downs and we are having a refresh issue.

The site has 4 drop downs - All of which grey out (other than the first) on page load - first selects tyre Width - 2nd then displays available profile options based on the first choice - 3rd displays rim sizes based on 1st and 2nd choices and fourth selects a rating based on top 3 choices.

Each drop down has an associated function - which is triggered via an onChange event.

as in -

```
 $('.sel0').on('change', function() {
    alert('sel 0 selected');
    $(".sel1").removeAttr("disabled");
    //populate function for sel1

 });
```

The issue we are having is that if the user changes a parent drop down (ie the 1st profile option) to a different result - some of the results in the 2nd option may be the same as on the previous selection - so if for example the user picked a width of 155, then a profile of 70 and so on - then changed their mind and wanted a width of 145 width a profile of 70 - 70 would ALREADY have been selected in a previous choice so the function associated with this drop down would not trigger as its 'on change' rather than 'on click'.

As onclick events don't work on drop downs we need an alternative solution - but are yet to discover one!

I've created a js fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/s60mLvsm/2/) to recreate my problem - select all options then try and reselect an options thats already selected - obviously due to onchange the  alerts wont fire..  help!?

Any suggestions for an onclick or onselect style solution please advise!

Comment: create a fiddle and share

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code :**

```
$('.sel0').on('change', function() {
    //alert('sel 0 selected');
    $('.sel1').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.sel1 option').eq(0).prop('selected', 'selected');
    $('.sel2 option').eq(0).prop('selected', 'selected');
    $('.sel3 option').eq(0).prop('selected', 'selected');
    $('.sel2, .sel3').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
});

$('.sel1').on('change', function() {
    //alert('sel 1 selected'); 
    $('.sel2').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.sel2 option').eq(0).prop('selected', 'selected');
    $('.sel3 option').eq(0).prop('selected', 'selected');
    $('.sel3').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('.sel2').on('change', function() {
    // alert('sel 2 selected'); 
    $('.sel3').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.sel3 option').eq(0).prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

- Try to shorter this if you can.